# ImportError: cannot import name 'build_py_2to3' from 'distutils.command.build_py'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-3.11

I tried to install bipwallet through pip but it says there is no 'build_py_2to3' in distutils

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting bipwallet
...
Collecting protobuf==3.0.0a3
  Using cached protobuf-3.0.0a3.tar.gz (88 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-install-q8v8yny3/protobuf_3f1a8b67130540ab9c93af7fe765918c/setup.py", line 29, in <module>
          from distutils.command.build_py import build_py_2to3 as _build_py
      ImportError: cannot import name 'build_py_2to3' from 'distutils.command.build_py' (/home/orkhan/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build_py.py)
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I tried to search in Google but it did not help. I also tried
`pip install --upgrade distutils`
thinking maybe it's just older version.

P.S. my python version 3.11

Comment: build_py_2to3 is most likely deprecated - also you are trying to install protobuf version that dates back to 2015 -- 8 years old *pre-release* why ot anything newer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems as though `bipwallet` or one of its dependencies (`protobuf-3.0.0a3`?) wants to use whatever version of `setuptools` is available rather than pinning a specific version. `setuptools` v58.0.0 has a [breaking change](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/47b724639703d0c512f275a316dbb99e6c226e38/CHANGES.rst#v5800), first included in Python 3.10, where `build_py_2to3` was removed.

You have a couple options:

1. Find the offending library and edit its `setup.py` to indicate that it should use `setuptools<=57.5.0` and retry.
2. Downgrade your Python installation to 3.9 to get a local version of `setuptools` prior to the breaking change.

Here are a couple other related posts/links to the issue you're seeing:

- https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/issues/1813
- https://bytemeta.vip/repo/StanfordVL/iGibson/issues/227
- https://github.com/mobinmbn/bipwallet_fix