Installing module with pip fails, is it possible to edit the versions?
I am trying to install pywallet
pip install pywallet
This fails at some point:
  Downloading protobuf-3.0.0a3.tar.gz (88 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-install-_xihs08_/protobuf_2395cbc163b34a7cb79f530d9bda1b24/setup.py", line 29, in <module>
          from distutils.command.build_py import build_py_2to3 as _build_py
      ImportError: cannot import name 'build_py_2to3' from 'distutils.command.build_py' (/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build_py.py)
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

I understand this is not a pip error, but a dependency inside the module fails to build.
Somewhere I read this is due to not fixing the version to a specific one, and the suggestion was to find the culprit and edit the setup.py.
But - as far as I can see, after the install fails everything is cleaned up.
Can I somehow download this thing, and manually edit the dependencies?
pip download pywallet fails with the same error.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75085575/importerror-cannot-import-name-build-py-2to3-from-distutils-command-build-py , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ImportError%3A+cannot+import+name+build_py_2to3

Try pip install --upgrade "setuptools<58" and pip install pywallet

This reminds me of the phrase "you cannot put new wine in an old wineskin". You are using Python 3.12 for a package that was last updated in 2018.
Looking at PyPi, the stable release of pywallet supports Python 2.7, 3.4 - 3.6. This is the likely reason for the dependency issue.
If you must use this package, you may have to downgrade your Python to a supported version or preferably (IMO), use a similar package or library.

OK I see, I used pyenv, has been quite a ride but it kinda worked in the end.
